# react native refactor theme handling

Tags: react.js, react-native

I am styling my react native component according to some conditions, here the code, The question is how do I make this cleaner? functional style?

```
const configColors = (isSingle, isDarkMode) => {
  let colors = {};

  if (isDarkMode){
    colors = {
      ...colors,
      configAxisLabelColor : Colors.white,
      configAxisGridColor : Colors.gridLineGray
    }
  }else{
    colors = {
      ...colors,
      configAxisLabelColor : Colors.lineGray,
      configAxisGridColor : Colors.transparent
    }
  }

  if (isSingle && !isDarkMode) {
    return colors = { 
      ...colors, 
      configAxisColor: Colors.transparent,
      configLineColor: Colors.lineGreen,
      configTooltipBackground: Colors.lineGreen,
    }
  }
  if (isSingle && isDarkMode) {
    return colors = { 
      ...colors, 
      configAxisColor: Colors.white,
      configLineColor: Colors.lineBlue,
      configTooltipBackground: Colors.lineBlue,
    }
  }
  if (!isSingle && !isDarkMode) {
    return colors = { 
      ...colors, 
      configAxisColor: Colors.lightBarGray,
      configLineColor: Colors.lineGray,
      configTooltipBackground: Colors.lineBlue,
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a ternary operator.

```js
const configColors = (isSingle, isDarkMode) => {
  return {
      configAxisLabelColor : isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.lineGray,
      configAxisGridColor : isDarkMode ? Colors.gridLineGray : Colors.transparent
      configAxisColor: isSingle ? (isDarkMode ? Colors.white: Colors.transparent) : Colors.lightBarGray
      // so on
  }
```

Another option that reads better could be to create a separate config for each possible combination you want to return.

```
const configColors = (isSingle, isDarkMode) => {

  const configSingleDark = {
    configAxisLabelColor : Colors.white,
    configAxisGridColor : Colors.gridLineGray
  }

  if (isSingle && isDarkMode) {
    return configSingleDark
  } else if (isSingle && !isDarkMode) {
    return configSingleLight
  } else {
    //
  }
}
```